# Django formtools how to store form data between logout/login cycles

Tags: django, session, cookies, django-formtools

I am using django-formtools to split a long form in parts. This is working fine. However, I want users to be able to start filling the form going until let's say step 5 out of 9, then logout and login again and continue filling the form from step 5 on.

I can do this with cookies but, if user A starts filling the form then logs out and then user B logs in, user B can see the data of user A if user B chooses to continue filling the form. This happens if users A and B use the same computer and web browser. This, of course, cannot happens.

If I use sessions instead of cookies then when a user logs out it is not possible to continue filling the form from step 5 on because the session is flushed and the data deleted. So I guess that sessions will not help me here.

In order to continue filling the form from step 5 on I override the get method of `django-formtools.WizardView`:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """ To allow resume editing of a session storaged submissions """
    if self.continue_fill == True:
        try:
            return self.render(self.get_form())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
#---
```

`self.continue_fill` is set in `urls.py` as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'new/', 
        views.SubmissionsWizardView.as_view(), 
        name='submission_new'
    ),
    path(
        'resume/', 
        views.SubmissionsWizardView.as_view(continue_fill=True),
        name='submission_resume',
    ),
]
```

So my questions are:

1.- Is it possible to associate cookies with a single user in Django?

2.- In my case user A and B can see their data because I am using the same PC, same web browser and same login user in the PC because I am still developing the site. But in general, will the cookie for user A using user A's account in the PC be different than the cookie for user B using user B's account in the same PC and of course using the same web browser? How are cookies separated for different users in a web browser in general?

3.- Is there any possibility of making this work (logout/login continue filling) using sessions?

4.- What if I want to allow users to have several form instances in different filling steps? Does django-formtools support this?

5.- I guess I could create a table to temporarily store the data in the form and associate the row with a user and then update the row for every step in the form or override the logout method to make sure that the cookie/session data is stored in the DB. This would allow having several saved forms that the user could continue editing but it is a lot of work. Any simpler alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the last option, on saving the form data in to the database is the most straightforward and secure way. The form wizard functionality sometimes distracts me from what I actually need to do. So I try to see the task from another angle.

For me this would be the simplest solution:

1. Create a Django model for each form.
2. Create a model form for each respective model.
3. Somehow (middleware, view...) check which model is missing and redirect user to the next step.
4. When the last model is populated process as needed.
5. If all models are present then don't redirect.

Comment: Thanks, but since it is a really long form I hope I do not have to go down this road